# Manipulating Civil TIN surface vertices Autocad C#

Tags: c#, autocad

My goal is to modify lots of vertices in an existing Civil TIN surface and place different groups of vertices on different elevations.

My problem is: whatever I try to do, I get thrown an error saying "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" on the second time I try to access the TinSurfaceVertex as part of a bigger operation. I've tried using both the surface.SetVerticesElevation(vertices, elevation) and surface.SetVertexElevation(vertex, elevation) - but both throws me the same error for the second vertex or group of vertices.

[image]

What am I missing?

Here's some code:

```
public void levelTheVertexGroups()
{

    foreach (VertexGroup group in this.verticeCollection) // VertexGroup is a custom class
    {

        List<TinSurfaceVertex> runVertices = new List<TinSurfaceVertex>();

        // Filter out the vertices that have not yet been modified
        foreach (TinSurfaceVertex vtx in group.ContainedVertices)
        {
            // Create a unique key for the vertex based on its location
            // in order to filter out already updated vertices
            // THIS BELOW LINE TRIGGERS THE NOTED ERROR ON 
            // THE SECOND RUN OF THE ORIGINAL FOREACH (VertexGroup-loop)
            string key = VertexGroup.CreateUniqueVertexKey(vtx.Location);
            if (!usedVertices.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                // Add it to the vertexes to update
                runVertices.Add(vtx);
                usedVertices.Add(key, vtx);
            }
        }

        // Get the AutoCAD Editor
        if (runVertices.Count > 0)
        {
            CivilDocument civilDoc = CivilApplication.ActiveDocument;
            using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
            {

                // Open for write
                TinSurface modSurface = tr.GetObject(this.createdSurfaceId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as TinSurface;

                // Modify the vertices
                modSurface.SetVerticesElevation(runVertices, 0.0);
                modSurface.Dispose();

                // Commit the transaction
                tr.Commit();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that as soon as some of the vertices in the TIN surface gets modified, all vertices get tagged to be inaccessible by Civil, and the remaining loops are made useless.

This code works like a charm if i only have one VertexGroup.

I hope someone can help. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

The original code I submitted reflects the case that once any TinSurfaceVertex gets accessed after the first SetVerticeElevations()-call, the error will be thrown. My code has nothing to do with it. I can set `var test = vtx;` and the same error will trigger on that exact line on the second loop.

The same error also occurs in the following situations:

```
foreach (VertexGroup group in this.verticeCollection)
{

        CivilDocument civilDoc = CivilApplication.ActiveDocument;
        using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {

            // Open for write
            TinSurface modSurface = tr.GetObject(this.createdSurfaceId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as TinSurface;

            // Modify the vertices
            // THIS LINE RETURNS THE ERROR ON THE SECOND LOOP RUN
            modSurface.SetVerticesElevation(group.ContainedVertices, 0.0);

            // Commit the transaction
            tr.Commit();

        }

}
```

And for this case as well:

```
CivilDocument civilDoc = CivilApplication.ActiveDocument;
using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{

    // Open for write
    TinSurface modSurface = tr.GetObject(this.createdSurfaceId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as TinSurface;

    foreach (VertexGroup group in this.verticeCollection)
    {
        // Modify the vertices
        // THIS LINE THROWS THE SAME ERROR ON LOOP NR 2
        modSurface.SetVerticesElevation(group.ContainedVertices, 0.0);
    }

    // Commit the transaction
    tr.Commit();

}
```

And this case, editing one vertex at a time:

```
CivilDocument civilDoc = CivilApplication.ActiveDocument;
using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{

    // Open for write
    TinSurface modSurface = tr.GetObject(this.createdSurfaceId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as TinSurface;

    foreach (VertexGroup group in this.verticeCollection)
    {
        // Modify the vertices
        foreach(TinSurfaceVertex vtx in group.ContainedVertices)
        {
            // THIS LINE THROWS THE SAME ERROR ON LOOP NR 2
            modSurface.SetVertexElevation(vtx, 0.0);
        }
    }

    // Commit the transaction
    tr.Commit();

}
```

If I'm only editing one (1) vertex, or a single (1) group of vertices, all of the cases works like a charm. Is there an issue in the C3D-API?

Comment: I don't believe you need (or should) call TinSurface.Dispose inside the transaction... otherwise the object will not be properly handled by the Commit call.

Comment: And I would suggest you call .Rebuild method, as you're handling the same surface before finish the command.

Comment: Calling the  .Dispose()- or .Rebuild()-methods makes no difference, I've tried all alternatives with them. I have roughly 5000 groups of vertices. Calling the .Rebuild()-method for each of them is really not an option (and it does not work either). @AugustoGoncalves Do you have any other suggestions? I still get the same error...

Comment: Reading your question again: does the exception throw at "VertexGroup.CreateUniqueVertexKey(vtx.Location)" call? If so, that not on C3D API, but on your code...can you clarify?

Comment: I've updated the post @AugustoGoncalves it's not my code throwing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out myself.

The issue occurs because I try to access a vertex that is stored in the VertexGroup, and is invalid because it was stored before change was made to the surface.

The solution is to re-fetch the vertex you need to modify, based on its location like this:

```
CivilDocument civilDoc = CivilApplication.ActiveDocument;
using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{

    // Open for write
    TinSurface modSurface = tr.GetObject(this.createdSurfaceId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as TinSurface;

    foreach (VertexGroup group in this.verticeCollection)
    {
        // Populate a list of all vertices to run
        List<TinSurfaceVertex> runVertices = new List<TinSurfaceVertex>();

        // Try this
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Point3d> keyVal in group.ContainedVerticePoints)
        {
            string key = keyVal.Key;
            if (!usedVertices.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                // Re-fetch the vertex at xy
                // THIS IS THE MAGIC
                TinSurfaceVertex vtx = modSurface.FindVertexAtXY(keyVal.Value.X, keyVal.Value.Y);

                // Add it to the vertexes to update
                runVertices.Add(vtx);
                usedVertices.Add(key, vtx);
            }
        }

        // Only modify if not already modified
        if (runVertices.Count > 0)
        {
            // Modify the vertices
            modSurface.SetVerticesElevation(runVertices, 0.0);
        }

    }

    // Commit the transaction
    tr.Commit();

}
```